# java execturorService - submit task and catch exception

Tags: java, runnable, executorservice, callable

I am trying to submit a task to an ExecutorService in Java. It either takes a Callable, which allows to throw an Exception, or it takes a Runnable. My use case is as foolows: I would like to schedule a task which throws an Exception, but is a void method. As a result I cannot use either Callable or Runnable, as the method definitions do not match my use case. I would also like to have my excepton propagated from the Future I receive after submission. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Callable<Void>`. Obviously you can't instantiate a Void object, but just return `null`.

From the `Future<Void>`, you can still call `get`, discarding the `null` return value. It will rethrow any exception as an `ExecutionException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `Callable<Void>` (or indeed any other class parameter) and always return `null`, in which case `Future.get` will *wrap and rethrow* any exception thrown by the task, or use `Callable<Throwable>` and have the body of your task be

```
try {
  // do stuff
} catch(Throwable t) {
  return t;
}
return null;
```

in which case `Future.get` will *return* the exception. In both cases a successful task will return `null` from its `Future.get`.